# insert (this.state) type variables directly into the JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I'm new to react and ES6. I want to print the data of the (this.state) type variables.

My code creates a random string and I was able to do that. I can print the this.state.resultCode directly to the console but not able to print its value in a 'p' tag.

My code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Checkbox } from 'react-bootstrap';

class ButtonComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      smallLetters: false,
      capitalLetters: false,
      numbers: false,
      specialCharacters: false,
      resultCode: ''
    }
  }

  generateCode(){
    let mask = '';
    if(!this.state.smallLetters && !this.state.capitalLetters && !this.state.numbers && !this.state.specialCharacters){
      mask = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]:";\'<>?,./|\\';
    } else {
      if (this.state.smallLetters) mask += 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
      if (this.state.capitalLetters) mask += 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
      if (this.state.numbers) mask += '0123456789';
      if (this.state.specialCharacters) mask += '~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]:";\'<>?,./|\\';
    }
    let result = '';
    for (let i = 32; i > 0; --i)
      result += mask[Math.floor(Math.random() * mask.length)];
    this.setState({resultCode: result});
    console.log(this.state.resultCode);
  }

  toggleChange(number){
    if (number == 0){
      this.setState({smallLetters: !this.state.smallLetters});
    }else if (number == 1) {
      this.setState({capitalLetters: !this.state.capitalLetters});
    }else if (number == 2) {
      this.setState({numbers: !this.state.numbers});
    }else if (number == 3){
      this.setState({specialCharacters: !this.state.specialCharacters});
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <form>
        <div className="form-check">
            <Checkbox className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" onClick={() => this.toggleChange(0)}>
             <label className="form-check-label">Small Characters a-z</label>
            </Checkbox>
        </div>
        <div className="form-check">
            <Checkbox className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" onClick={() => this.toggleChange(1)}>
             <label className="form-check-label">Capital Characters A-Z</label>
            </Checkbox>
        </div>
        <div className="form-check">
            <Checkbox className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" onClick={() => this.toggleChange(2)}>
             <label className="form-check-label">Numbers 0-9</label>
            </Checkbox>
        </div>
        <div className="form-check">
            <Checkbox className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" onClick={() => this.toggleChange(3)}>
             <label className="form-check-label">Special Characters</label>
            </Checkbox>
        </div>
        </form>
        <button className="btn btn-outline-primary generateButton" onClick={() => this.generateCode()}>Generate CODE!</button>
        <p>{this.state.resultCode}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default ButtonComponent;
```

this component is exported as

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ButtonComponent from './components/global';

ReactDOM.render(
    <ButtonComponent />, document.getElementById('generateButton')
)
```

I tried dangerously set innerhtml, tried changing 'p' tag to 'div' tag and different approaches from other questions posted here but even that didn't work.

So, what's the correct way to print the data of the this.state.resultCode

Edit: In future if anyone is having this problem, then refer to this code. The code is now working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are directly assigning a property of the state to another value. This is called mutation and it is a no-no in React. Doing something like `this.state.numbers = !this.state.numbers` does not trigger a re-render of your component. You need to use `setState` whenever you want to change the state of your component. [Read more here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly).